# Function receiving unexpected type

Tags: python, code-reuse

Consider the following code. When `function_a()` is called it will then call `function_b()`. Inside `function_b()` if the "unwanted" situation occurs, `function_c()` is called. If things go normal, `var` is returned instead and `function_a()` finishes correctly.

**The problem is:**
I'd like to have the following working in a way that when `function_c()` is called, the program stops because it corresponds to the unwanted behavior. Also, `var_x` will have `'error message'` which `Function` at `function_a()` does not expect (e.g. unexpected type).

```
def function_c():
    return 'error message'

def function_b():
    if some_condition:
        return function_c()
    return var

def function_a():
    var_x = function_b(var_y)
    return Function(val_x)
```

I know there is a way to do this without having to use `exit()` or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean "the program stops"?  Do you mean you want to raise an exception?

Comment: Well, you can do `raise ValueError, 'Error message'`.  If you need more info than that you'll have to be more specific about what you want.  You haven't provided enough information to know what kind of exception would be appropriate.

Comment: Change `return 'error message'` to `raise Exception('error message')`